# Xml parsing in Iphone and adding values to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to xml parsing. I have the following xml

```
<myMainList>
            <mySubList>
              <edited>true</edited>
              <mySharedNumber>W59QYBZKJ4</mySharedNumber>
           </mySubList>
           <mySubList>
              <edited>false</edited>
              <mySharedNumber>TOW4KLP9WD</mySharedNumber>
           </mySubList>
           <mySubList>
              <edited>true</edited>
              <mySharedNumber>XH8JDIZA64</mySharedNumber>
           </mySubList>
           <mySubList>
              <edited>false</edited>
              <mySharedNumber>V2YOHSNODT</mySharedNumber>
           </mySubList>
   </myMainList>
```

I have edited my question.

I am not familiar with looping through the whole xml and adding the values into my array. Can someone show me how I can add the 4 `sharedNumberList` values into my array.

Edit:

```
GDataXMLElement *node;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray * array = [node nodesForXPath:@"//return/myMainList/mySubList" error:nil];
            NSLog(@"count  :%d",[array count]);
            int sharedContacts = [array count];

            NSMutableArray *mySharedListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


      for(int i = 1; i<= sharedContacts; i++){
                NSString *xmlDataFetcher = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//return/myMainList/mySubList[%d]",i ];
                NSString *parsedNumbers = [node nodeStringForXPath:[xmlDataFetcher stringByAppendingString:@"/mySharedNumber"]];
                NSString *parsedEdit = [node nodeStringForXPath:[xmlDataFetcher stringByAppendingString:@"/edited"]];
                NSLog(@"Parsed Edited %@", [node nodeStringForXPath:[xmlDataFetcher stringByAppendingString:@"/edited"]]);
                NSLog(@"Parsed sharedNumber %@", [node nodeStringForXPath:[xmlDataFetcher stringByAppendingString:@"/mySharedNumber"]]);
                NSString *arrayEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", parsedNumbers, parsedEdit];;

                [mySharedListArray addObject:arrayEntry]; 
            }
            NSLog(@"Array entry %@", mySharedListArray);
```

I have added a lot of `NSLog` in the answer, so that you could log it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this most probably this is returning an array from the xpath query so Try this instead

```
[mySharedListArray addObjectsFromArray:[node nodesForXPath:@"//return/MyList" error:nil]];
```

Comment: It shows `incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSArray *' `

Comment: @JeanPaulScott please look at my edit... this will surely work.

Comment: The `nodesForXPath` method also has an `NSError **` parameter.